# Ways in which Spring do Dependency Injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have some experience in Spring Framework. Spring usually do the DI using the `constructor injection` or `setter injection`. This concept I am comfortable. Now, in addition to this, I have seen the Spring do DI like this:

```
@Autowired
DataSource myData;
```

**OR**

```
@Resouce(name="someName")
SomeDependency dependency;
```

What mechanism do Spring utilise when it uses annotations to do the DI?  Does Spring use `constructor` or `setter` injection in these cases or is annotation driven approach altogether a different way of injecting the dependencies?

Any explanation in simple worlds would be of great help.

Comment: Neither. This is called field injection and preferably should be avoided (imho that is) (see http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/)

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for your inputs, however I have seen this approach being widely used. So wondering what happens behind the scenes of annotation approach.

Comment: The fact that is being widely used doesn't mean it is a good approach...

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for your reply and the link that your provided earlier, very informative. I wanted to clear my doubts instead of keeping them in mind. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do setter injection and constructor injection by `@Autowired` means.

```
@Autowired
private Person person;

@Autowired
public Customer(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}
```

By default autowired inject beans by TYPE. Behind the scene it makes injection via java reflection mechanism. So you can do the same things(that you've done with xml config) with annotation config.

In addition want to add that constructor injection is more preferable(except cases where there are to much arguments). 
Main advantage of constructor injection:

- You can't avoid passing arguments to constructor and create bean without them.

So in most all cases you want dependency to be injected, while setter injection doesn't guarantee it(you can get this annoying NPE that appears during wrong setter injection).

Specific rules of autowired using : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: this is regarding the first line of code in your example, what spring will do ? will it call the setter of person object for this Customer class for DI?

Comment: setters are not necessary because spring uses reflection. And you can autowire even PRIVATE fields without setters.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, I was trying to understand the thing. I have autowire on one of my private field and setter is also there for that private field but while executing my application that setter is not executing.

Comment: @IvanLymar: Thanks so much for your reply, very useful. So this means that using `Autowired` annotation, it can be applied on `private fields`, `setters` and `construtors`. And in all these cases Spring use Reflection to do the Injection? Practically which is the preferred way?

Comment: As i already said constructor injection is best practice,but it requires more code writing(that's why many people skip this advice and use setters).